# Can we implement the URL Reqwriting on IIS in shared hosting?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-7, shared-hosting

Can we implement the URL Re Writing Of IIS level on a shared hosting provider? According to my findings we can't but our project manager said we can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possible very much using HttpHandlers e.g.

```
<httpModules>
   <add type="URLRewriter.ModuleRewriter, URLRewriter" 
        name="ModuleRewriter" />
</httpModules>



<httpHandlers>
   <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" 
        type="URLRewriter.RewriterFactoryHandler, URLRewriter" />
</httpHandlers>
```

More info at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx)

Comment: Satya its in web.config settings i just want to do it on IIS level

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Rewrite feature of IIS 7.5 , please refer following link for guidance

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module

Comment: i just want to know is it available for shared hosting?